# Project files cannot be found on Dockerfile Copy command

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core

I have .net core project (`MySolution.Web.API`) which referencing couple of .net standard 2.0 projects 
(`MySolution.Infrastructure` and `MySolution.Domain`)

on my hard drive solution looks like this

```
    .vs/
    bin/
    packages/
    MySolution.Infrastructure/
    MySolution.Domain/  
    MySolution.Web.API/
    .dockerignore
    docker-compose.yml
    ....
    MySolution.sln
```

Inside MySolution.Web.API there is Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY MySolution.Web.API.csproj Web.API/
COPY MySolution.Infrastructure.csproj MySolution.Infrastructure/
COPY MySolution.Domain.csproj MySolution.Domain/

RUN dotnet restore MySolution.Web.API.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/MySolution.Web.API
RUN dotnet build MySolution.Web.API.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish MySolution.Web.API.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MySolution.Web.API.dll"]
```

When I try to create an image with

```
docker build -t mysolution.web.api .
Step 1/20 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
 ---> db030c19e94b
Step 2/20 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c46d1d16c23c
Step 3/20 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 615befacb30c
Step 4/20 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
 ---> 06a6525397c2
Step 5/20 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d8b8d0f73449
Step 6/20 : COPY MySolution.Web.API.csproj MySolution.Web.API/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bcfb36743124
Step 7/20 : COPY MySolution.Infrastructure.csproj MySolution.Infrastructure/
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder805773291/MySolution.Infrastructure.csproj: no such file or directory
```

Since Dockerfile is inside MySolution.Web.API/ folder I tried to change path on copy command inside Dockerfile to

```
COPY ../MySolution.Infrastructure.csproj ../MySolution.Infrastructure/
```

but I'm not allowed to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that

```
MySolution.Infrastructure.csproj
```

is outside of the build context of the Docker image.
Running docker build command like that

```
docker build -t mysolution.web.api .
```

tells Docker deamon that only files from current folder takes part in Docker image building. You have to change your build context path. Try to use

```
docker build -t mysolution.web.api ..
```

and modify files paths in the Dockerfile according to new build context path.

For more information check documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with-path