# Azure devops build failed NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops

I have .net solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54939411/project-files-cannot-be-found-on-dockerfile-copy-command). Its basically .net core app which referencing couple of .net standard projection.
.net core api project is containerized and I'm able to start application locally as linux dockerized app.

Now I moved source to the azure devops and I cannot build the app. It constantly failing with message:
  ....

```
Build FAILED.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.104/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.ObsoleteReferences.targets(33,5): warning NETSDK1059: The tool 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet' is now included in the .NET Core SDK. Information on resolving this warning is available at (https://aka.ms/dotnetclitools-in-box). [/home/vsts/work/1/s/MyProject/MyProject.Web.API.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.104/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.ObsoleteReferences.targets(33,5): warning NETSDK1059: The tool 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet' is now included in the .NET Core SDK. Information on resolving this warning is available at (https://aka.ms/dotnetclitools-in-box). [/home/vsts/work/1/s/MyProject/MyProject/MyProject.eb.API/MyProject.Web.API.csproj]
LocationDbContext.cs(29,32): warning CS0114: 'LocationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken)' hides inherited member 'DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/MyProject/MyProject.MyProject.Infrastructure/MyProject.Infrastructure.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.104/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1179,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/MyProject/MyProject.Tests/MyProject.Tests.csproj]
    3 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:01:21.41
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: dotnet build Release
```

**Update:**
*azure-pipelines.yml*

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build MyProject/MyProject.sln --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This project references assemblies from framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1". You might remove the project from the solution or fix project dependencies.

> /home/vsts/work/1/s/MyProject/MyProject.Tests/MyProject.Tests.csproj